# How to count all day events onload of the FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using Full Calendar for my project, I need to get the count of daily appointments onload of the calendar.
Link of the plugin: https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Where are you loading the event data from? If it's from your own server-side event feed, then surely it would be easier to count the data items using server-side code and just return the totals to the browser. P.S. Please see [ask] because your post is not a high-quality one by stackoverflow standards - you are supposed to give more context, show some existing code where you tried to achieve it and explain where you're stuck. "I need" isn't a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you the number of events (appointments) in your current view, where `calendar` is a reference to your FullCalendar object.

```
calendar.getEvents().filter(x => (x.start >= calendar.view.currentStart && x.end <= calendar.view.currentEnd)).length
```

you could put that in `datesSet`

```
datesSet(dateInfo) {
    var numberOfAppointments = calendar.getEvents().filter(x => (x.start >= calendar.view.currentStart && x.end <= calendar.view.currentEnd)).length;
}
```

You could further filter it down to  specific day, or create an array of appointments per day perhaps.

The above is based on **FullCalendar v5**

**Update - get a count per day**

use this to produce a date and count per day.

```
var daysInViewWithEventCounts = [];
for (var d = new Date(calendar.view.activeStart); d <= calendar.view.activeEnd; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    daysInViewWithEventCounts.push( {"date": new Date(d), "count": calendar.getEvents().filter(x => (x.start.toDateString() == d.toDateString())).length} );
}

console.table(daysInViewWithEventCounts);
```

you could then loop that and do something with the data.

```
daysInViewWithEventCounts.forEach(entry => {
    var theDate = entry.date;
    var theCount = entry.count;

    // do something with the data
    console.log(theDate);
    console.log(theCount);
});
```

Comment: can you please explain this a bit more, how can i achieve for each day on a month view?

Comment: ok @AmeerHamzaKhan, my original code got the full count of bookings / events for the whole view. I have amended my answer to show you how to get a count 'per day'.

Comment: Can you please help me out to set the number to specific date in a month view, i am not able to set the value and facing difficulties to find the id or class for the particular date...

Comment: @AmeerHamzaKhan you can get a count for a particular date like this `var theDate = "2022-07-28"; 
var theDateCount = calendar.getEvents().filter(x => (x.start >= new Date(theDate + "T00:00:00") && x.end <= new Date(theDate + "T23:59:59"))).length;`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Okay, Thankyou for this, Do you have any idea how to append the count to the day cell in a month view?

Comment: Thank you so much for this, IT worked perfectly fine, One last thing, do you have any idea how to append this count to a specific date cell?@MikeIrving

Comment: I am using full Calender version 5.0

Comment: you could use something like this (jQuery) `$("[data-date='2022-09-07']").append("<div class='calendar-div-total'>my test</div>");` and then in CSS style up `.calendar-div-total { ... }` as you wish @AmeerHamzaKhan