# How to get the count in month view of each day in fullcalendar-5.10.1

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am using a full calendar-5.10.1 for my project, the requirement is to show the count of appointments each day in a month view.
I am getting the total appointments by using this code but didn't able to separate them for each day.

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
                    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                        timeZone: 'America/New_York',
                        themeSystem: 'default',
                        eventColor: 'green',
                        editable: true,
                        eventDisplay: 'auto',
                        slotDuration: '00:05',
                        slotMinTime: '07:00',
                        slotMaxTime: '17:00',
                        displayEventTime: false,
                        showNonCurrentDates: false,
                        headerToolbar: {
                            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',
                            center: 'title',
                            left: 'prev,next,today'
                        },
                        events: 'load.php?doc_session=' + doc_session,
                        selectable: true,
                        allDaySlot: false,
                        datesSet(dateInfo) {
                            // var numberOfAppointments = calendar.getEvents().filter(x => (x.start >= calendar.view.currentStart && x.end <= calendar.view.currentEnd)).length;
                            var numberOfAppointments = calendar.getEvents().filter(x => (x.start >= calendar.view.currentStart && x.end <= calendar.view.currentEnd)).length;
                            console.log(numberOfAppointments);
                        }
    });
calendar.render();
```

Comment: What is your expected result? What would it look like? How do you think you'd do it?

Comment: @Kinglish Kindly check the link for reference: https://ibb.co/NZ4zRyt

Comment: Ok, a count of events per day. Without your code and your attempt, not much I can do. You are able to get a count for the month - you can use the same logic to get a count per day. You could either use a reduce loop to create an array of counts, or a for loop for each day, then count the events. Either way, where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I am stuck at, not able to set this code for each day, currently this 2 lines of code returns the complete events list,either its on month view, it will return from start date to end date events, if on day view will give the number of all day events.
I need to get the count of each day in a month view.

Comment: can you paste in an example of your dataset you're using? (paste into your question)

Comment: @Kinglish Kindly check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count all day events onload of the FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72006362/how-to-count-all-day-events-onload-of-the-fullcalendar)

Comment: @MikeIrving Yes